# How to move/reorder columns in LXTask?

Tags: 15.04, lxde

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 with LXDE.
Is there any (hidden or non hidden) way to change the column order of LXTask?
(I know, it's a very new and rarely seen feature for 2015)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy method to do that.

To do that you have to edit  the source file and change whatever you want.

```
apt-get source lxtask
```

This will download the source file of the package. Mainly you'll have two files `lxtask_0.1.4.orig.tar.gz` and `lxtask_0.1.4-1.debian.tar.bz2`.

Now extract the `lxtask_0.1.4.orig.tar.gz` and then

```
cd path-to-extracted/lxtask-0.1.4/src
```

In the directory you'll find a file named `interface.c`

Open it with your favorite editor

```
gedit interface.c
```

search for function `create_list_store` under it you'll find the way of building the columns so there you an swap between the columns as you like.

Once you've finished you have to install again from source

```
./configure
make
```

and then

```
sudo make install
```

**PS:** I didn't try it myself since there is some dependency problems with gtk in my system. But this is a start where you can try and test yourself

Comment: Wow, thanks for this detailed answer (including Source-File).

Comment: @Ben you are welcome, Please give me a feedback when you test it